# Enable TLS 1.2 on Windows 2008 for 32-bit applications

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, iis-6

I'm trying to enable TLS 1.2 for outgoing connections from a classic ASP site running on IIS. I have tried adding the registry settings outlined in the questions below but this hasn't helped.

[Check if Windows Server 2008R2 can use TLS 1.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/862509/check-if-windows-server-2008r2-can-use-tls-1-2)
[How do I disable TLS 1.0 without breaking my IIS/ASP.NET websites?](https://serverfault.com/questions/800634/how-do-i-disable-tls-1-0-without-breaking-my-iis-asp-net-websites)

The app pool for this site has Enable 32-bit applications set to True. I noticed that if I create a new site and set Enable 32-bit applications to False then outbound traffic from the test site uses TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server 2008 requires an update to enable support for TLS 1.1/1/2:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019276/update-to-add-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows

RDS support for TLS 1.1/1.2 Windows 2008 R1 SP2
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074621/add-rds-support-for-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-in-windows-server-2008-sp2

Comment: Just to clarify, setting the app pool to Enable 32-bit Applications = False allows outbound TLS 1.2 connections. My specific issue seems to be concerned with when 32-bit applications are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using MITMProxy to bump up the traffic from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2.